# Unable to change file association on Mac OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion, file-association

I'm trying to change a file association for an entire extension for an application called Eagle CAD. Currently, the .brd and .sch files are associated with apps called pcbnew and eeschema respectively.

I've removed these apps in favor of Eagle CAD, and now having difficulty changing the associations.

When I right click the file, and select Get Info, I change the association to Eagle CAD, and click Change All, like so:

[image]

However, what happens is, when I click Change All, the drop down immediately flips back to the old pcbnew / eeschema association, and the preview icon also indicates the old association.

No matter what I do, it doesn't want to change the association?

Comment: One observation I made, is when I change the association to for example Preview, it persists the change successfully.